# java print other side of pyramid nested loop

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I'm currently stuck on creating the other side of my pyramid. I would like for my program to ask the user for a number between 5 and 15. Use that number to print out a square and a triangle. I have been able to do everything up until I get to the pyramid. I can create one side of the pyramid but I noticed i'm overlooking something when it comes to creating the other side. Any guidance on putting me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class doLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        final int minimum = 5;
        final int maximum = 15;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between" + " " + minimum + " " + "and" + " " + maximum + ":" );
            number = input.nextInt();

            for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
                    System.out.print(j + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for(int column = 1; column <= number; column++) {
                for(int row = 1; row <= number ; row++) {
                    if(column >= row) { 
                        System.out.print(row);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            if (number <= minimum || number >= 15) 
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid");
        } while (number <= minimum || number >= maximum); 
    }
}


**Here is my current output:**

Enter a number between 5 and 15:5
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1     
12    
123   
1234  
12345 
Sorry, invalid
Enter a number between 5 and 15:

**This is what i'm working towards:**

Enter a number between 5 and 15: 2
Sorry, 2 is invalid.  Please try again.
Enter a number between 5 and 15: 20
Sorry, 20 is invalid.  Please try again.
Enter a number between 5 and 15: 10

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


                            1
                         2  1  2
                      3  2  1  2  3
                   4  3  2  1  2  3  4
                5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5
             6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6
          7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
       8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: welcome to SO. please put yourself in the shoes of people who might answer your question. a square and a triangle? at least show us what the output is supposed to look like

Comment: "print a full pyramid" - i can imagine so many ways of how you could "print a pyramid" just put in the asciis you want to show up and everything will be 100% clear

Comment: You talk about a 3D object (pyramid) and "printing it". I assume by "printing a pyramid" you mean "making some console output", i.e. a 2D ascii-image. This invovles at least a projection and a discretization. Your explanation is not precies. as @LonelyNeuron said, please show at least the output you got so far and what the full output is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You code has multiple errors!!!

1. your code will loop forever
2. you don't need a `do loop`
3. If I understand correrctly your problem is that you want the left side of the pyramid. You can achieve it by looping from negative user input to the values inserted by the user

Here's a snipped code, you need some tweaking based on your needs!!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class doLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        final int minimum = 5;
        final int maximum = 15;

        System.out.print("Enter a number between" + " " + 
               minimum + " " + "and" + " " + maximum + ":");
        number = input.nextInt();

        if (number <= minimum || number >= 15) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int row = 1; row < number; row++) {

            for (int column = -(number - 1); column <= number; column++) {
                int absValue = Math.abs(column);
                // you need to use the absolute value 
                // to print the positive value and to perform column checks
                if (absValue <= row)
                    System.out.print(absValue);
                else {
                // if the absolute value is greater the the current print 1 or 2 spaces 
                // based on the value of the column 
                //(2 spaces if lower then 10 otherwise 1 space only)
                    System.out.print(absValue < 10 ? " " : "  ");
                }
                // If the absolute value of column is -1 or 1 you need to change 
                // the value to "1" to bypass the printing of 101
                if (absValue == 1)
                {
                    column = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather edit what I have worked on as opposed to just copying what you did. Plus, I don't understand all of your code. I was able to complete the triangle I was looking for. But for some reason I can't get my loop to follow the conditions I set. It worked initially before I added the for loops for the shapes but now i'm stuck on how to get it to follow them again. Any advice?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class doLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number;
    final int minimum = 5;
    final int maximum = 15;




    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number between" + " " + minimum + " " + "and" + " " + maximum + ":" );
         number = input.nextInt();

    if (number <= minimum || number >= maximum) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid");
   break;
}
                for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {

        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + "  ");

        }
        System.out.println();

        }
                int columns = 1;

                for (int i = number; i >= 1; i--)   
                {
                     for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++)
                     {
                         System.out.print(" ");

                }
                for (int j = i; j <= number; j++) 
                {
                    System.out.print(j + " ");
                }

                for (int j = number - 1; j >= i; j--)
                {
                    System.out.printf(j + " ");
                }

                    System.out.println();

                    columns++;
                }





    } while (number <= minimum || number >= maximum); 




}


}
```